# issues with jquery date dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="img/logo.png" id="logo" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="searchbox">
                    <div id="search-input">    
                        <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"/>   
                        </div>        
                    </div>        
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-1" id="search-button">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
                            <img src="img/search.png" class="img-responsive"/>
                        </button>
                    <span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" id="login-name">
                    <p> Logged in: John Smith </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/settings.png" id="settings-icon" class="img-responsive"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <!-- Static navbar -->
             <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    <li class="active" id="active-link"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                     <li class="dropdown">
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
             </nav>   
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="banner-top-row">
              <div class="col-md-12" id="banner-top-col">
                <img src="img/banner-top.png" id="banner-top" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
                  <div class="banner-information text-center">
                  <h4> For more information.... </h4>
                  <h1> Contact Us </h1>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="row" id="detail-request">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1> Send us your details to request our latest brochure <h1>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="map-holder-image">
                    <img src="img/map-holder.png" class="img-responsive"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form class="form">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                <label for="first-name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                <label for="email-address" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-address">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                <label for="last-name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                <label for="confirm-email-address" class="control-label">Confirm Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="confirm-email-address">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <input type="hidden" id="date-dropdown">
                <script>
                $("#date-dropdown").dateDropdowns({
                    defaultValue: "2010-02-17"
                });
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="submit-button" type="button">
                    <h3>Submit</h3>
                </button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="support-box">
                    <h3>Start a Live Chat with one of our Tech Team</h3>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="support" type="button">
                        <h3>Start</h3><img src="img/button-icon-livechat.png" id="support-image" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="support-box">
                    <h3>Start a Skype Call with one of our Sales Team</h3>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="support" type="button">
                        <h3>Start</h3><img src="img/button-icon-skype.png" id="support-image" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="support-box">
                    <h3>Send an email to our Customer Services Team</h3>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="support" type="button">
                        <h3>Start</h3><img src="img/button-icon-email.png" id="support-image" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" id="banner-bottom-row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="banner-bottom-col">
                <img src="img/banner-bottom.png" id="banner-bottom" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
                <div class="banner-information text-center">
                    <h4> We will be in touch </h4>
                    <h1> Thank you </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="footer">
            <p>Terms and Conditions   |   Privacy Policy   |   Copyright Code 2016</p>
        <hr id ="footer-line">
        </div>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-date-dropdowns.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://gyazo.com/06ad94c6b0c0b173da9dfd1d95bb02f6 here is my browser loading in the jquery js. My error message is

contact-us.html:121 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ contact-us.html:121

Comment: Maybe you can describe the problem?  We can't see your screen from here.

Comment: Nothing is displayed

Comment: Sounds like you haven't included the jQuery library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the jquery library to the head of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This should solve it.

The `$ is not defined(anonymous function)` means jQuery hasn't been loaded yet

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector is incorrect in two ways:

1. `"example1"` is looking for an element called `<example1>`, which of course doesn't exist.  To select an element by its `id`, prepend a `#` character.
2. Your element's `id` is `example3`.

Try:

```
$("#example3")
```

Comment: @user6073700: Yes it does: https://jsfiddle.net/nx8w28t9/  You need to specify what "doesn't work" means.  In what way does it fail?  Is there an error in the browser's JavaScript console?  Have you successfully loaded the JavaScript files?  When you debug it, does the jQuery selector find the element you expect it to?  Are there other elements with the same `id`?

Comment: here is my code

            <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <input type="hidden" id="date-datedrop-menu">
                <script>
                $("#date-datedrop-menu").dateDropdowns({
                    defaultValue: "2010-02-17"
                });
                </script>
            </div>


my error message is contact-us.html:121 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ contact-us.html:121

Comment: @user6073700: `$ is not defined` means that you didn't load jQuery.  The library you're using is a jQuery plugin, to jQuery has to be loaded first in order for it to work.

Comment: I put        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> on top of my scripts load in page

Comment: @user6073700: You're going to have to debug this in your browser's tools then.  Clearly jQuery is not loaded, according to the error you're getting.  Maybe that file can't be found?  Maybe you're loading it after loading the plugin?  Maybe something else?  The code itself works just fine.

Comment: I really don't understand this, I can see the js file in the browser debug and I have double checked everything but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @user6073700: Is there a live example you can provide which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @user6073700: In the updated code you're loading jQuery *after* you try to use it.  It needs to be loaded *before* you try to use it.  That's why it's not defined yet.